# Drag and Drop child node to parent node using angular.treeview and angular ui-sortable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, treeview, angular-ui

Hi Im new to angularjs and im using this treeview directive [angular.treeview](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview) matched with Angular-ui **ui-sortable** directive

So i modified angular.treeview.js and added ui-sortable tag to `<ul>` tag to make it work:

```
//tree template
            var template =
                '<ul ui-sortable>' +
                    '<li data-ng-repeat="node in ' + treeModel + '">' +
                        '<i class="collapsed" data-ng-show="node.' + nodeChildren + '.length && node.collapsed" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeHead(node)"></i>' +
                        '<i class="expanded" data-ng-show="node.' + nodeChildren + '.length && !node.collapsed" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeHead(node)"></i>' +
                        '<i class="normal" data-ng-hide="node.' + nodeChildren + '.length"></i> ' +
                        '<span data-ng-class="node.selected" data-ng-click="' + treeId + '.selectNodeLabel(node)">{{node.' + nodeLabel + '}}</span>' +
                        '<div data-ng-hide="node.collapsed" data-tree-id="' + treeId + '" data-tree-model="node.' + nodeChildren + '" data-node-id=' + nodeId + ' data-node-label=' + nodeLabel + ' data-node-children=' + nodeChildren + '></div>' +
                    '</li>' +
                '</ul>';
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zg3f9/1/

The problem is that i want the child nodes to be draggable to their parent or other nodes. can you guys help me with this? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a library that already supports this? Like [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree), or, if you want to use the HTML5 Drag & Drop API, [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/)

Answer (score 0):

My Example:
http://codepen.io/Yizhu/pen/EPLxEW

```js
scope.sortableOptions = {
  connectWith: ".apps-container",
  update: function(event, ui) {   
    var index = ui.item.sortable.index;
    var dropindex = ui.item.sortable.dropindex;
    var dropTargetModel = ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel;
    var dragModel = ui.item.sortable.model; 
    
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.